# How to completely disable YouTube iframe fullscreen? - Youtube Iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I'm already creating the YouTube player with

```
playerVars: {
    controls: 0,
    fs: 0,
    disablekb: 1
}
```

but on double click, it still goes to fullscreen, although it pauses then continues the playback. So if I could disable just the fullscreen part, it would be working fine.

(How) is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating the iframe by myself, I've managed to resolve the issue.
Here is the code:

```
const createYtPlayer = (videoId, container = inv) => new Promise(resolve => {
    const el = document.createElement('iframe');
    el.frameBorder = 0;
    el.setAttribute('allow', 'accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture');
    el.setAttribute('donotallowfullscreen', '');
    el.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&origin=' + encodeURIComponent(window.origin);
    container.appendChild(el);

    const player = new YT.Player(el, {
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        videoId,
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            fs: 0,
            disablekb: 1
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': () => {
                setBestSoundQuality(player);
                player.setVolume(100);
                resolve(player);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

})();

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

It turned out that its probably a bug. I did a workaround with the help of @Paul Fitzgerald's answer, because that worked.

For some reason, if the allowfullscreen is present in any way, the `donotallowfullscreen` attribute has no effect (and the allowfullscreen is added automatically).

So I added

```
const iframe = player.getIframe();
iframe.removeAttribute('allowfullscreen');
iframe.setAttribute('donotallowfullscreen', '');
```

to the onReady event, and it works.

**EDIT:** it only seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: do you maybe have a fiddle of the above suggestion, to see it work?

Answer (score 2):

In the iframe you can put `donotallowfullscreen`

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/test"  donotallowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Weird. I tought `fs: 0` should disable the fullscreen. Then I added donotallowfullscreen and it still didn't work. For some reason, the API added allowfullscreen="1", which effectively disabled the effect of donotallowfullscreen. But if I remove the allowfullscreen and add donotallowfullscreen, it works, yay!